# Lambda in dict iterator giving last value

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I was doing a complicated aggregation in pandas and found an unusual issue in Python dictionaries.

When I do:

```
g = {
    "grade": dict(
        ["is_" + val, (lambda x: val)]
        for val in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
    )
}
```

I was expecting I would get multiple functions: `g['grade']['is_A']`, `g['grade']['is_B']`, `g['grade']['is_C']`, ... each of which will give back `A`, `B`, `C`, ... respectively.

The thing is they all give me return the value `F` (the last item in the iterator)

```
In []: g['grade']['is_A'](1)
Out[]: 'F'

In []: g['grade']['is_B'](1)
Out[]: 'F'

In []: g['grade']['is_C'](1)
Out[]: 'F'

...

In []: g['grade']['is_F'](1)
Out[]: 'F'
```

Even doing lambda without the argument gives the same value. I am assuming this is happening because when I run the `lambda`, it is looking for the variable `val` and finding that the `val` refers to 'F' in the last iteration.

Is there any way for me to use the actual value in a dictionary generator ?

I basically want to create like 300-400 functions for is_VALUE where the values are dynamically being fetched from another place.

Comment: Short answer: the variable inside a lambda function is evaluated when executing but not creating.

Comment: You can fix that with `lambda x, val=val: val`. But why do you even _want_ a function that ignores its arg and returns a constant? Surely there's a more efficient way to do what you're trying to do

Comment: yeah, this was a stripped down example - the arg is used along with the `val` in the actual function.